# How to auto detect number of li tag in scss

Tags: html, sass

I'm writing navi in header like this.

```
<div id="navi">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is scss file for it.

```
$navi_items: 5;
#navi{
  width: $page_width;
  margin: 0 auto;
  ul.menu{
    li{
      padding:10px;
      width: $page_width/$navi_items - 20 ;
      float:left;
    }
  }
}
```

When I add new item in navigation I must change `$navi_items` value.
Is it possible to detect number of li automatically and reflect it in scss?

I know I can do it with javascript. But I want to know how to do it with scss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

SCSS is compiled down to pure CSS which is **not** designed for interacting with the DOM.

The only possibility would be to either choose a better CSS or to create some JS.